# How to configure to_lower_case property for the auto_index

Tags: neo4j

I would like to make the default of auto_index "to_lower_case" so the searches over the auto_index insensitive to cases. How I should do it?

Tried to find out in the manuals, forums, etc., with no success.

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

I think you can configure the index as a fulltext index which will help you with case insensitive searches.

Configuration:

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-configurable-auto-indexes.html

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/indexing-create-advanced.html